# How to script text output based on binary value

Tags: javascript, java, niagara-ax

Hi awhile back a college of mine, made this script for Email address, by combing Email addresses together based if a Binary value is active as Input.

I want to change it abit, so that the mailaddress goes out to different outputs based on a binary value.
Here’s the problem: 
I have a lot of caretakers who has a lot of building they keep track over. They need to receive mail on different times (I.E X amount of people receive first, then 3 other gets mail 15 minutes later. Etc.) 
Ive decided to have 4 categories at each building. They decide which build and categories they want. And I generate a binary value (numeric) Out of their selection.

I want to use that binary value. To send out their mail address on different outputs, combining them altogether, to be used in the TO: Field in a mail.

If there is any help, im using this code for a program block in Niagara Ax

Here’s the code my collage way back made, I want to change from True/false input to Binary input. 
Where the binary value (bit) corresponds to outputs. But I’m having a hard time figuring it out.

```
public void onStart() throws Exception
{
  // start up code here
}

public void onExecute() throws Exception
{
  // execute code (set executeOnChange flag on inputs)
  String emailRecipients = "";
  int n = 0;

  if (getEnable_A1().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_1().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A2().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_2().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A3().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_3().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A4().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_4().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A5().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_5().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A6().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_6().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A7().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_7().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A8().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_8().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A9().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_9().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (getEnable_A10().getValue() == true)
  {
    emailRecipients+=getMailAddress_10().getValue();
    emailRecipients+=';';
    n++;
  }

  if (n>0) // one or more enabled ...
  {
      // strip trailing ';' ... 
      int l = emailRecipients.length();

      if (emailRecipients.substring(l-1, l).equals(";"))
      {
          emailRecipients = emailRecipients.substring(0, l-1);
      }
  }
  else if (n == 0) // No mail recipients enabled ... 
  {
    emailRecipients = "";
  }
  setAddressListOut(BEmailAddressList.make(emailRecipients)); 

  // "debug"
  getRecipients().setValue(emailRecipients);
  getN_Recipients().setValue(n);
}

public void onStop() throws Exception
{
  // shutdown code here
}
```